# Can a gerundial noun take an article before it?

Tags: gerunds

Can a gerundial noun take an article before it, and what differences does having an article  make?

If so would this be the case: "I chose it for it had not been chosen, though the choosing it would make it to have been chosen."

Comment: Can you give an example that is like to be used in normal speech? This is too intricate and unlikely to be said.

Comment: Be careful: gerunds are verbs, so they can hardly take a determiner. In your example, "choosing" is a gerundial noun (or just noun). Btw, what does the sentence mean? Where did you find it?

Comment: _The choosing it_ is not grammatical. _The choosing of it_ would be, though unusual.

Comment: The sentence isn't a quote, I was just wondering if that could be possible. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: For this sentence, *my* choosing works better than *the* choosing. I think maybe you should remove the *to have been* also. I also suspect that using *my* instead of *the* might mean that you don't need to add the *of* that Sandip describes, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: *I chose it for it had not been chosen* doesn't look syntactically valid for any context I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Gerund is a double parts of speech : partly a noun and partly a verb :

> *"I like **reading** a novel"*

Here, *'reading'* is a gerund. As a verb, it has an object *'a novel'*· As a noun, it is the object of the verb *'like'*.

But if *'reading'* is preceded by the article 'the' & followed by 'of', then 'reading' is only **'a verbal noun'**.

> *"I like the reading of a novel".*

Here, 'reading' acts only as a noun (object of the verb 'like'), it doesn't take an object as a verb. Here, 'a novel' is the object of the preposition '

So, your sentence should be :

> "I chose it for it had not been chosen, though **the choosing of it** would make it to have been chosen."

Here, 'choosing' is not a gerund. It's a 'verbal noun' or a 'gerundial noun'.

Comment: _I like reading a novel_ is best analysed as a **catenative** construction where "like" is a catenative verb and the non-finite subordinate clause "reading a novel" is not object but catenative complement of "like".

Comment: A catenative verb (also called a chain verb) takes as its complement a nonfinite construction (often an infinitive) : "She *seems to want to stop trying to avoid* meeting him."

Comment: *"I like reading a novel."* In this sentence *'like reading'* forms a catenative construction. Here, the catenative verb *'like'* has taken a gerund (a nonfinite construction) as its object.

Comment: Not quite: catenative clauses like "reading a novel" are not objects, but catenative complements. That's one of the major syntactic points about the catenative construction. In "I like reading a novel", "like" is a catenative verb and "reading a novel" is its catenative complement.

Comment: But that's not the point of discussion of the original question.